# Can I use the maven war as a form of overwriting the other projects that already exist?

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, war

I am beginner on Spring and Maven.

In Spring Framework,
I want to manage a separate version control flow.

```
1. Main Project that already exist.
2. Module of the partial use that packaged by maven war.
```

Two projects should be treated separately when Push and Pull.

But Files on two projects may be present in the same folders.

How can I use this?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually related with version control system you currently use. Git for example supports submodules. You can create a maven module directly in your root project folder and define it as git submodule. So they have different git tracks and may seperately maintained.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But As I written in the body text, I want to manage 2 project's file on same folder. For example, there are 2 files that related ui but one belong to main project and other one belong to submodule.

Comment: Oh sorry I overlooked that they should be in the same folder. For that I don't know any appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you need might be achievable by using 'war-overlays' as documented [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html)

To summarize, you specify the 'child' project as a dependency in the 'Main' project:

```
...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example.projects</groupId>
      <artifactId>documentedprojectdependency</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>war</type>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
  ...
```

And you define the overlay in the `maven-war-plugin`'s configuration:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <overlays>
                <overlay>
                    <id>my-webapp-index.jsp</id>
                    <groupId>com.example.projects</groupId>
                    <artifactId>my-webapp</artifactId>
                    <includes>
                        <include>index.jsp</include>
                    </includes>
                </overlay>
                <overlay>
                    <!-- empty groupId/artifactId represents the current build -->
                </overlay>
            </overlays>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer may be good solution for my case. I'll read document you recomand.